# D3.js multiple or automatic scales in a sortable table

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to build a sortable chart based off of Mike Bostock's recent health care chart on NYT: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/09/24/us/health-care-premiums.html

[image]

My issue is that my some of the columns in the chart require a custom scale, rather than a single scale for the entire key. I am wondering if there is a technique for assigning a custom scale for each column or set thereof?

Mike's table has a single scale for all the columns within the key:

```
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 11000])
        .range([0, 320]);
....

  row.transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 8; })
    .selectAll(".g-table-bar")
      .each("start", function(d) { this.style.width = x(d) + "px"; });
```

Ideally, I would like to assign a automatic variable scale based on each individual variable/column. Is this possible? It seems that d3.min and d3.max can only be used for an individual variable but it's likely I'm wrong.

Thanks. Ian

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It looks to me that, within a column, the same scale is used for everything?